# DB connection issue

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm going through this code and can't quite crack it. Please help, I'm tring to get a database connection between two files and keep getting an error on first code at lines starting with // Connect to Client Database and can't seem to figure it out, I've tried multiple different ways about going about this issue.

this is the k_dbfunctions code

```
<?php
//session_start();

/**
 *  PDO Class
 */ 
class PDOData {

    private $dbhost;
    private $dbuser;
    private $bdpass;
    private $dbnamee;
    private $connection = null;

    /**
     *  DBO Class Constructor
     *  Get config file data and assign into instance variables.
     *
     *  Get Database Connection
     *  Default connect to admin database.
     *  @return connection if connection is successful.
     */
    function __construct() {
        // Get database credentials from config file.
        $path = "k_db.php";
        $data = include($path);

        if(is_array($data)) {
            $this->hostName   = $data['hostinfo goes here'];
            $this->userName   = $data['db name goes here'];
            $this->password   = $data['password goes here'];
            $this->dbName     = $data['db name goes here'];
        }

        // Connect to Client Database
        if(isset($_SESSION['admin']['b00635911'])) {
            $this->dbName = $_SESSION['admin']['b00635911'];
        }

        // Make Connection
        if($this->connection==null){
            $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);

            // Check Connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();die();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Check Authentication
     *  Check record is found in table or not.
     *  If found it will return true otherwise return false
     *  @return boolean
     */
    function checkAuthentication($query){
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($this->connection, $query));

        if(isset($result['id']) && !empty($result['id'])){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Insert record in table.
     *  @return if inserted sucessfully then return last id otherwise return false
     */
    function insetData($query){
        if (mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) === TRUE) {
            return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Return all table records.
     *  @return Result Set
     */
    function getData($query){
        return mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    }

    /**
     *  Update record
     *  @return boolean
     */
    function updateData($query){
        if (mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) === TRUE) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Delete Record
     *  @return boolean
     */
    function deleteData($query){
        if (mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) === TRUE) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the k_db code

```
<?php

//Connection credentials
 $dbhost="db host name here";
 $dbuser="db user here";
 $dbpass="my db password";
 $dbname="my db name";


//Creating mysqli object
$mysqli_connect= new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


//Error handler 
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    printf("Connection failed %\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately including doesn't work like that, you need to actually use the variables themselves:

```
$path = "k_db.php";
include($path);

$this->hostName   = $dbhost;
$this->userName   = $dbuser;
$this->password   = $dbpass;
$this->dbName     = $dbname;
```

Also, theres no need to create the MySQLi connection in `k_db.php` and then again in your class constructor. By creating it in `k_db.php` then including it your class, such a connection already exists in `$mysqli_connect` within the same scope.

The only time using `$data = include('/file/script.php')` is meaningful for getting custom data is when the script you are including uses `return`. See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php